# Extracting heading levels above code chunk in R markdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, markdown

If I had for example,

````
~~~
# Heading 1

## Column

### Heading 3 

```{r, echo=F}

```
~~~
````

above a code chunk in R-markdown. I notice that 'Heading 3' will get printed above a plot or table, or some other output. My question is: is there a way to extract the third-level heading of that code chunk and print it to the output also? For example, this could be used as the filename of a plot. I would also appreciate solutions for pulling out other levels (i.e. first-level and second-level). Thank you for your help.

I have tried using `knitr::opts_current$get("label")` or other similar solutions but label is not right here and will print nothing. I am left wondering if that's the correct line of thinking or if there's another. The solution shouldn't be based on the position of the code chunk in the text (i.e. using `readLines()` and grepping)